# how to install NVIDA toolkit (using package manager, cant give .deb file name)

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have been using NVIDIA and CUDA for months. This morning, after ubuntu update, I get 'CUDA not found' error. Ah, I've installed NVIDA toolkit, driver and CUDA a couple of time on this machine using .run file. Reading the "NVIDIA CUDA Getting Started Guid for Linux" document again, I decided to try installing package manager so uninstalled previous .run install files as directed in the document. 
The manual says I should first give this command.

`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb`

but I don't know how to replace the `distro` `version` and `architecture`.
See the uname and lsb_release result.

```
ckim@abnc:~$ uname -a
Linux abnc 4.4.0-34-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:56:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ckim@abnc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I tried `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-14.04_7.5_x86_64.deb` but didn't work. What should the command be? (I tried amd64 instead of x86_64 in vain). From http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.5-ubuntu, I guess it's `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_x86_64.deb` but it also failed. (I previously installed cuda7.5-18 using .run file)

EDIT : The problem was I didn't download the actual .deb file as directed in the preinstall step in the document. See comments below. For .run file installation, see the answe by @Terrance.

Comment: Did you actually download the package like the sentence before that code says to do?

Comment: Ah, should I?  I'll check. :)

Comment: @Zacharee1 after installing the .deb file, I could run the procedure and CUDA runs ok again! thanks! (The command in my case was `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install the DEB file, you'll need to actually download it. The guide has a link for the CUDA download site: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Answer (score 0):

The following is something that I have done recently, so I hope it might help you.

---

The `NVIDIA-370` drivers that are in the `graphics-drivers` ppa actually have the CUDA library with it.

First, set up the `graphics-drivers` ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then update and install drivers:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-370
```

Go to your `~/Downloads/` folder, then download the cuda run package:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/prod/local_installers/cuda_8.0.44_linux-run
```

Rename the new file downloaded:

```
mv cuda_8.0.44_linux-run cuda_8.0.44_linux.run
```

Then make a directory to work with for the cuda toolbox:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/nvidia_installers
```

Then extract the different parts of the installer into the folder (has to be full directory name):

```
sh cuda_8.0.44_linux.run -extract=/home/<username>/Downloads/nvidia_installers/
```

Go to the nvidia folder:

```
cd nvidia_installers/
```

Install the samples and the runtime:

```
sudo sh cuda-linux64-rel-8.0.44-21122537.run
sudo sh cuda-samples-linux-8.0.44-21122537.run
```

*You don't need the drivers as they are already installed.*

Then to test your installation, go to:

```
cd /usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
```

Change all files to be owned by you:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER *
```

Then run make to compile the deviceQuery:

```
sudo make
```

Then you should be able to run the `deviceQuery` to show you the information:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 560 Ti"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 959 MBytes (1005387776 bytes)
  ( 8) Multiprocessors, ( 48) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1700 MHz (1.70 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2100 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 2 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 560 Ti
Result = PASS
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I have done something like that before (installing using .run file) a couple of times and this time I did it using .deb file. The problem was that I didn't download the actual deb file as directed in the pre-installation step. Thanks for the writing and it'll be a good reference for others.

Comment: @ChanKim I actually didn't see that you got it installed.  Glad that you did.  I guess I can leave this here for now.  =)