# Driver: Installation Failed Toolkit: Installation skipped

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, gpu

I can't install CUDA 8 Toolkit on Ubuntu 14.04. I get this error:

-

```
$ sudo ./cuda_8.0.44_linux.run 
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Do you accept the previously read EULA?
    accept/decline/quit: 
    Do you accept the previously read EULA?
    accept/decline/quit: accept

    Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 367.48?
    (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: yes

    Do you want to install the OpenGL libraries?
    (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit [ default is yes ]: yes

    Do you want to run nvidia-xconfig?
    This will update the system X configuration file so that the NVIDIA X driver
    is used. The pre-existing X configuration file will be backed up.
    This option should not be used on systems that require a custom
    X configuration, such as systems with multiple GPU vendors.
    (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit [ default is no ]: y  

    Install the CUDA 8.0 Toolkit?
    (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

    Enter Toolkit Location
     [ default is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ]: 

    Do you want to install a symbolic link at /usr/local/cuda?
    (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

    Install the CUDA 8.0 Samples?
    (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

    Enter CUDA Samples Location
     [ default is /home/mona ]: 

    Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
    It appears that an X server is running. Please exit X before installation. If you're sure that X is not running, but are getting this error, please delete any X lock files in /tmp.

    ===========
    = Summary =
    ===========

    Driver:   Installation Failed
    Toolkit:  Installation skipped
    Samples:  Installation skipped


    Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_1976.log
```

Thsi are the log files: http://pastebin.com/KLAZ4b5g and http://pastebin.com/wRJq8t51
I also had installed this Nvidia driver for Tesla K40c GPU prior to installing the CUDA 8 Toolkit.

```
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.93.02.run
```

Any guidance as what to fix?

Comment: Always install the Nvidia drivers though `apt-get`. Never any other way, unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: Nvidia website has suggested to install it this way rather than apt-get!!!

Comment: and yes, I know what I am exactly doing

Comment: Errrrmmm... well... ask just about anyone here, and they'll you to only install via `apt-get`.

Comment: You think this answer might help?  http://askubuntu.com/a/818510/231142

Answer (score 1):

Firstly pay heed to the warning:

```
This option should not be used on systems that require a custom
X configuration, such as systems with multiple GPU vendors.
```

On my laptop I have an Intel HD4000 GPU and Nvidia GT650M so it could be a warning for me. Be sure of what you are installing!

As far as the error message, you have to run the installation through the console when X-Server isn't running. Reboot your machine. At the normal Ubuntu gooey (GUI) login prompt press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and the console (text based) login will appear. Enter your user ID and password.

Then type:

```
sudo ./cuda_8.0.44_linux.run
```

Then reboot by typing:

```
sudo reboot
```

Login normally at the regular GUI prompt.

If there still is a problem post comment below.

Comment: I can't do this because i am trying to do this at a remote sshd machined and when i press those buttons my own ubuntu machine x server exits. Solution?

Comment: Sorry haven't delved into sshd yet. That's like a Christmas project.

Comment: @MonaJalal As painful as it sounds, call someone at the remote machine location and ask them to type in the commands. Maybe e-mail them the commands and have them print them out.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while here, but to help out others in this situation, look at the warning about an X server running. On Ubuntu, this usually means that you should stop lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

NOTE: You must be in a tty shell to do this, so you'll need to press ctrl + alt + F1 (Or most other function keys, if that didn't work).

Now run the NVIDIA installer.

NOTE: Stopping lightdm will kill your GUI, so you'll need to reboot or type the following command to restart it:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Since you'll have to reboot anyway, this is probably unnecessary, but I thought you'd like to know how to reverse it :)